# sqlalchemy session not recognizing changes in mysql database (done by other processes)

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlalchemy

Application consists of:

- main process (python+sqlalchemy) that
  periodically check db (sleeps   most
  of the time)
- child processes that write to db
- web app that write to db

Problem is that the main process session doesn't seem to register changes in the db done outside that session. How do ensure it does? (as of now I am closing and reopening the session every time the process awakes and does its check).

Comment: Do you do a commits?  Some code usually helps clarify what it is you're doing.  Please post the **smallest** pieces of code that clearly demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 1):

> I am closing and reopening the session every time the process awakes and does its check

SQLAlchemy will not work like this. Changes are tracked in the session.

```
someobj = Session.query(SomeClass).first()
```

puts `someobj` into `Session` internal cache. When you do `someobj.attr = val`, it marks the change in the Session associated with someobj.

So if you pulled object1 from some session1, then closed session1, object1 is not associated with any session anymore and is not tracked.

Best solution would be to commit right upon the change:

```
object1 = newsession.add(object1)
newsession.commit()
```

Otherwise you will have to manage own objects cache and merge all of them upon each check.